# Is it possible to use Ubuntu snapcraft offline?

Tags: snap

When I try to build a simple snap I get the error:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='parts.snapcraft.io', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/parts.yaml (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f99e296b7b8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
```

This is no surprise as our internet access is protocol-gapped. Is there a way around this? Nothing jumps out at me from the documentation...

This is on Ubuntu 16.04 desktop, rather than Snappy Ubuntu Core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

snapcraft can now be run offline, yes. The parts directory (which is being pulled via parts.snapcraft.io) is optional, and isn't checked by default.